# Meaning of いいなり

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of いいなり in the phrase

> セーブするにはポケモンレポートこまめにかくといいなり

Comment: It's a [キャラ語尾](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) most associated with [this character](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E5%8A%A9). Who's the speaker? A real person may use a キャラ語尾 randomly to make the sentence sound interesting.

Answer (score 4):

It appears this character is using なり, an old copula roughly equivalent to だ or です in the modern day, as just something they say at the end of their sentences to give them an 'old' feel. なり did not follow し adjectives, the precursor to い adjectives, as し could stand on its own. かくとよし would be equivalent to かくといいです or かくといいよ (though I'm not sure if the と conditional was used at the time)

Comment: It's a board in professor Oak's lab. I thought いいなり could be something like "as was Said", because the phrase is a instruction about save the game